# Updating Azure KeyVault

Tags: azure, version, azure-keyvault

we are using Azure KeyVault to store our client secret of the storage accounts at Azure. This secret is used at ADF.
Our secret is expiring soon so we wanted to update the stored secret which seems to be not possible if you are not using some code.
One can only create a new version of the secret which is useless because a new URI is created which has to be updated manually at each ADF pipeline. We wanted to avoid this manually work.
Is there a more simple way to update the secret than using code?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this blog https://blog.eldert.net/reference-key-vault-secret-latest-version/ by Eldert Grootenboer.

So if you change the URI at the web activity at ADF, to get access to the KeyVault secret from https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/secretname/1aa9707ba40eet28e52310ef36bf6g5f8 to https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/secretname/?api-version=7.0, you get the current version of your secret.

So if your secret expires, create a new one and create a new version of the 'KeyVault Secrets' (current version). Your pipeline will go on with this new secret.

It is, as mentioned at the blog, *"not officially suported by Microsoft"* (I also opened a ticket), but it works.

Cheers.

Comment: For storage accounts and other resources that supports managed identity I strongly recommend using [managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#managed-identity). Then you do not have to store the account key as a secret.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will have a closer look at this